# MYSQL workbench like gui tool for oracle 10 g or more

Tags: mysql, oracle-11g, oracle-10g, rdbms, dbms

I am a java full stack developer who want to write oracle sql queries to simplify writing is there any mysql workbench like similar gui tool for oracle by oracle or any other please sugest

[image: Click on the image to open]

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/database/sqldeveloper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle SQL Developer

You can download it [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/).

[image]